# How to sort an array with PHP, ignoring the articles (a, an, the) in the beginning?

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

Suppose I have the following array `$books` (the actual array is much larger):

```
Array
(
    [0] => The Mystic Masseur
    [1] => The Suffrage of Elvira
    [2] => Miguel Street
    [3] => A House for Mr Biswas
    [4] => Mr Stone and the Knights Companion
    [5] => The Mimic Men
    [6] => A Flag on the Island
    [7] => In a Free State
    [8] => Guerrillas
    [9] => A Bend in the River
    [10] => The Enigma of Arrival
    [11] => A Way in the World
    [12] => Half a Life
    [13] => Magic Seeds
)
```

When I use the `sort` function, the result is this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => A Bend in the River
    [1] => A Flag on the Island
    [2] => A House for Mr Biswas
    [3] => A Way in the World
    [4] => Guerrillas
    [5] => Half a Life
    [6] => In a Free State
    [7] => Magic Seeds
    [8] => Miguel Street
    [9] => Mr Stone and the Knights Companion
    [10] => The Enigma of Arrival
    [11] => The Mimic Men
    [12] => The Mystic Masseur
    [13] => The Suffrage of Elvira
)
```

But I would like to ignore the articles (a, an, the) in the beginning and would like to have a result like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => A Bend in the River
    [1] => The Enigma of Arrival
    [2] => A Flag on the Island
    [3] => Guerrillas
    [4] => Half a Life
    [5] => A House for Mr Biswas
    [6] => In a Free State
    [7] => Magic Seeds
    [8] => Miguel Street
    [9] => The Mimic Men
    [10] => Mr Stone and the Knights Companion
    [11] => The Mystic Masseur
    [12] => The Suffrage of Elvira
    [13] => A Way in the World
)
```

I’ve tried:

```
$_books = array();
foreach($books as $book){
    if(substr($book, 0, 4) == "The "){
    $_books[substr($book, 4)] = $book;
    }
    else if(substr($book, 0, 3) == "An "){
    $_books[substr($book, 3)] = $book;
    }
    else if(substr($book, 0, 2) == "A "){
    $_books[substr($book, 2)] = $book;
    }
    else{
    $_books[$book] = $book;
    }
}
ksort($_books);
$books = array_values($_books);
```

But I know this is not the best solution because it has the risk of losing values (e.g. if there are both “A Fantasy” and “The Fantasy” in the input, there will be only “The Fantasy” in the output). So, what is the best solution?

Comment: The question then is what do you want in the output? both?

Comment: Define your own sorting function, and check the beginning of the word for the existence of the articles

Comment: @Tim Yes, I want both.

Comment: The answer by Niet the Dark Absol should be interesting for you then.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use a custom sort function:

```
function handleArticles($str) {
    list($first,$rest) = explode(" ",$str." ",2);
       // the extra space is to prevent "undefined offset" notices
       // on single-word titles
    $validarticles = array("a","an","the");
    if( in_array(strtolower($first),$validarticles)) return $rest.", ".$first;
    return $str;
}
usort($books,function($a,$b) {
    return strnatcasecmp(handleArticles($a),handleArticles($b));
});
```

Comment: To summarize what is happening here: Each entry in the array is reorganized to have the initial article moved to the end of the word, separated by a comma. For example: 'A Way in the World' becomes 'Way in the World, A'. This new string is then in a case insensitive string comparison of the custom sort function.

Comment: A non-obvious benefit to this method is the concatenation of the article to the end of the word, so that it is still used in sorting, but is secondary. Consider the following: 'A World of War', 'The World of War'. Removing 'A ' and 'The ' could result in these being sorted as 'The World of War', 'A World of War'. However, concatenating the article on the end ensures that these are always sorted as 'World of War, A', 'World of War, The' which results in 'A World of War', 'The World of War'

Comment: [This](https://eval.in/82187) throws some Undefined offset errors. What am I missing?

Comment: Ah, I see. It doesn't like single-word titles. See edit.

Comment: For anyone interested, use `uasort` instead of `usort` to maintain index association. I had non-integer indices that I needed to retain, and this simple change helped retain them after being sorted with the rest of the above code.

Answer (score 6):

**Edited.** Use custom function like this:

```
function customSort($a, $b) {
    $list = array(
        'The' => '',
        'A' => '',
    );
    $pattens = array();
    $replacement = array();
    foreach ($list as $from => $to){
        $from = '/\b' . $from . '\b/';
        $pattens[] = $from;
        $replacement[] = $to;
    }
     $a = preg_replace($pattens, $replacement, $a);
     $b = preg_replace($pattens, $replacement, $b);

     return strcmp($a,$b);
}
       $array = array("The Vendor", "The World of War", "A World of War");
       usort($array, 'customSort');

    print_r($array);
```

Result:

```
Array ( [0] => The Vendor [1] => A World of War [2] => The World of War )
```