# Laravel: How to sort eloquent collection ignoring articles of a language?

Tags: laravel, sorting, collections, eloquent

In laravel, is there any way of sorting the collection ignoring the articles in a language (like a, an, the in English; el, la in Spanish; etc.)?

I wanted something like [jQuery Tablesorter](https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-parsers-ignore-articles.html) for the titles but I could only find

[How to sort an array with PHP, ignoring the articles (a, an, the) in the beginning?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20744995/how-to-sort-an-array-with-php-ignoring-the-articles-a-an-the-in-the-beginni)

and [How to sort in SQL, ignoring articles ('the", "a', "an" etc)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3252577/how-to-sort-in-sql-ignoring-articles-the-a-an-etc).

It was fine if it was an array, but I have collection with pagination and it wouldn't make sense to sort the paginated results, as it would only sort the limited results instead of a whole collection.

Answer (score 1):

The answer by @Alexey does solve the problem if you do not have paginated collection, since I had pagination, I solved the issue by using [orderByRaw()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queries#raw-expressions) method and regular expression case match. Hope this helps someone in similar situation.

```
$query->orderByRaw("CASE
                        WHEN title REGEXP '^("a|an|the|el|la")[[:space:]]' = 1 THEN
                            TRIM(SUBSTR(title, INSTR(title, ' ')))
                        ELSE title
                    END ASC");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a closure to the [`sortBy()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/collections#method-sortby) or the [`sortByDesc()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/collections#method-sortbydesc) methods:

```
$collection->sortBy(function ($i) {
    return trim(str_replace([' a ', ' an ', ' the ', ' el '], '', ' ' . $i['title'] . ' '));
});
```

This code will add spaces to beginning and end of a string (i.e. `title` property in an object or an array in a collection). Then it will remove articles and will not remove words which have 'an' or 'the' (or some other article in it) or begin or end with an article. Then it will remove spaces from beginning and end of each string. Then it will return a sorted collection.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But the sort seemed to be case sensitive and AFAIK sortBy method is for collection and if I already have a paginated collection of 10 records out of 200, it is going to work only for the current collection of 10, right? I was thinking if it was possible to sort all the records first and then paginate.

Comment: @A.G. you can just list all variations, so a case-sensitive solution is ok here. Also, you've asked about collections and I gave you a solution for collections. But it looks like you need a raw query solution.