# Ordering By a Varchar column is that even possible?

Tags: php, laravel, sorting, alphanumeric

am using Laravel for some sass project where some deals are one step behind completion if just our rooms accepts ( alphabetic ) beside the actual numbers for example
101 - A101 ect.

So room_number column data type was int so i converted it to a varchar no problem until now and everything is working perfect .

Received a new request that we want to sort those rooms in a specific way so for example if i have rooms 101, 102,A101,103,B102 they must be sorted asc as 101,A101,102,B102,103

The Below Screen might give you something of what am trying to achieve

[image]

According to the screen room A101 must come after room 101 and room B102 must come after room 102 etc.

i tried the following

```
Room::where(.....)
->orderByRaw("CAST(room_number as UNSIGNED) ASC")
->get();
```

also i tried to sort the collecting after getting it

```
Room::where(.....)
    ->orderByRaw("CAST(room_number as UNSIGNED) ASC")
    ->get()
    ->sortBy('order', SORT_REGULAR, true);
```

But all my tries came to a dead road !
am thing to perform a binary search on those rooms and apply a custom solution but i thought i could ask first maybe someone had the same issue !

Comment: This question has some answers that may be of some inspiration: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47903727/laravel-how-to-sort-eloquent-collection-ignoring-articles-of-a-language
Maybe you can make the `sortBy` closure have the char moved to the end of the string so that it naturally sorts them after the number without any char.

Comment: Can you add columns to your table? One for prefix ('A' or 'B' ... in this case) and one for the number (101, 102, 103...) as integer of course. So you can order them by number first and prefix second.

Comment: @mulquin hmmm it seems a reasonable suggestion thanks

Comment: @UğurArıcı unfortunately it is a one column room_number but wait do you mean that instead of converting the room_number column from int to varchar i leave it as int then i add a new column maybe room_number_alpha  and when the user send the room number as E105 i split the incoming string and store it ?!!! please take into consideration that room_number must be unique

Comment: @EmadRashadMuhammed yes, for this specific need you can add 2 additional columns and auto set and update them according to base and unique `room_number` field. When you set anything to `room_number`, you can set `room_number_prefix` to `null` or given string and `room_number_integer` to given number. You can set both of them indexes on DB. It's not the nicest but may be a solution.

Comment: I think this solution works @mulquin suggest 
`
 ->sortBy(function ($i) {  return trim(str_replace(['A', 'B'], '', ' $i['room_number']. ' '));
                });`

Comment: Sorry i don't know how to comment with a code , but trimming the room_number and sorting do the trick i want to achieve @UğurArıcı i think i have to find a way to replace all the alphabetic ( lower and camel )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use either REGEXP_REPLACE() or REGEXP_SUBSTR() to extract numeric value for sort, here is a sample of how to do it

```
Room::where(.....)
    ->orderByRaw("REGEXP_REPLACE(room_number, '[^0-9]+', '') ASC")
    ->get();
```

or

```
Room::where(.....)
    ->orderByRaw("REGEXP_SUBSTR(room_number,'[0-9]+') ASC")
    ->get();
```

Note: If you need more customization consider use "*ORDER BY
CASE WHEN*"

Comment: First one solved my problem , actually if you saw the previous comments i managed to make it work inside the sort() after getting the collection but i think your solution is faster so am gonna accept it  thanks a lot